# Parsing JSON response from Stream

Tags: json, esp, stream

I want to parse JSON response from a GET Request. I do this usually by using a String variable to store the response and later parse this string using ArduinoJSON library like shown below:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "OTA.h"
#include "Credentials.h"
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

const char url[] = "http://date.jsontest.com/";

HTTPClient getClient;

void getRequest(String &payload)
{
  getClient.begin(url);

  int httpCode = getClient.GET();

  if (httpCode > 0)
  {
    payload = getClient.getString();
    // Serial.print("HTTP Status: ");
    // Serial.println(httpCode);
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Error on HTTP request");
  }
  getClient.end();
}

void parseResponse(String &payload)
{

  StaticJsonDocument<128> doc;

  DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, payload);

  if (error)
  {
    Serial.print("deserializeJson() failed: ");
    Serial.println(error.c_str());
    return;
  }

  const char *time = doc["time"]; // "03:53:25 AM"
  // unsigned long *epoch = doc["milliseconds_since_epoch"]; // 1362196405309
  const char *date = doc["date"]; // "03-02-2013"

  Serial.println(date);
}

void setup()
{
  setupOTA("ESP-N2", mySSID, myPASSWORD);

  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop()
{
  ArduinoOTA.handle();

  unsigned long newTime = millis();
  static unsigned long oldTime = 0;
  String payload;

  if (newTime - oldTime >= 5000)
  {
    oldTime = newTime;
    getRequest(payload);
    parseResponse(payload);
    Serial.println();
  }
}
```

I want to avoid using String and [ArduinoJSON offician reference](https://arduinojson.org/) page mentions that it's possible to deserialize directly from input Stream e.g. wifiClient, ethernetclient or serial but I couldn't find any example showing it's usage. So I am curious to learn how to use it.

From my basic understanding of a Stream, I suppose I need define a buffer or memory location that will hold the incoming bytes and using the address of this buffer need to read data bit by bit. So  do I need to do something like this:

```
char buffer[]= httpClient.getStream();
```

and then pass this buffer as input to deserialize function? or have I gotten it completely wrong?

Comment: https://arduinojson.org/v6/how-to/use-arduinojson-with-httpclient/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`httpClient.getStream()` returns an instance of [`Stream`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/stream/) that you can pass to [`deserializeJson()`](https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/json/deserializejson/), like so:

```cpp
deserializeJson(doc, httpClient.getStream());
```

However, by doing so, you bypass the code in `HTTPClient` that handles [chunked transfer encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding), so you must call `httpClient.useHTTP10(true)` before calling `GET` to make sure the server won't return a chunked response.

See [How to use ArduinoJson with HTTPClient?](https://arduinojson.org/v6/how-to/use-arduinojson-with-httpclient/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I am happy to learn the Stream usage. It works well but I also get                                                                                                                                   [D][HTTPClient.cpp:378] disconnect(): still data in buffer (1), clean up. 
[D][HTTPClient.cpp:387] disconnect(): tcp stop.                                                                               Since I am reading all the stream data, which data it might be referring to? Can it cause an issue like memory leakage or fragmentation?

Comment: I added ChunkedStreamReader to my StreamLib. it wraps an input Stream and decodes the chunked input:  https://github.com/jandrassy/StreamLib/blob/b9b31e7908479efd0149940df9de610439532506/examples/Advanced/ReadChunkedJSON/ReadChunkedJSON.ino#L36

Comment: I followed the approach mentioned in the docs but it seems that my GET requests fail when I use http1.0. My server is running on aws (amplify) and uses http2. What should I do in this case?